# Reset all subviews of UIView (e.g. textfields)

Tags: iphone, subview, reset

Is there a quick way on how to reset all the subviews like textfields, labels etc. to its original state like they are when they get initialized the first time? I guess dealloc and init again would not be the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking that `dealloc` and `init` would be somewhat useful, why not just invoke `release` and then re-init everything with the `alloc` and appropriate `init` combo?

I would probably opt for explicit resetting code, but unless there are a large number of views you are wanting to reset, I don't think that `release`, `alloc`, and `init` would be all *too* expensive.

Comment: I guess setting textfield = nil does not help as it's superview retains it? I think I just need to manually resetting all the code that I change...  thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 2):

dealloc is usually not supposed to be used. try init without alloc `mylabel = [mylabel init]`, but you're probably better off writing your own reset method and explicitly resetting each view

Comment: to init without alloc does not help. I will create my own reset method then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice says that When you allocate memory location to a object; as soon as its usage is over , you should release the object.

In your scenario, if you follow this practice; you just need to release the object when its usage is over with [object release] method.

Then everything will be in the way automatically, what you actually want in the problem.

Hope this information is useful.